# how to make a double json external call in react

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I need help. I am building a small react webapp which should make a list out of to different json calls. The first one should ask for the list. Foreach entry there should be a second json call, that give specific informations about every entry. I want to return it as a list in a div.

This is the code i am so far. The current code works but i cannot make the second call. Whatever i am trying doesn't work.

Thank you.

```
var Dashboard = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function(){
    return {
        coinListJson: "json/coinlist.json",
        coinList: [],
        coinInfo: []
    }
},
componentDidMount: function() {

    var th = this;
    this.serverRequest = 
      axios.get(this.state.coinListJson)
        .then(function(result) {
            th.setState({
                coinList: result.data.coins
            })      
        })
  },

render: function(){
    return (
        <ul>
            {this.state.coinList.map(function(val, index){

                return (
                    <li key={ index }>{val.id}</li>
                );

              })}
        </ul>
    )   
  }
});

React.render(
  <Dashboard/>,
  document.getElementById('dashboard')
);
```

i tried something like this:

```
render: function(){
    return (
        <ul>
            {this.state.coinList.map(function(val, index){



                    var th = this;
                    var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"+val.id+"/?convert=EUR";
                    this.serverRequest = 
                    axios.get(url)
                        .then(function(result) {
                            return (                     
                              <li key={ index }>{val.id}{result.data.coins[0].price_btc}</li>
                            );


                        })


              })}
        </ul>
    )   
  }
```

Comment: You need to get all your data ready in `componentDidMount`.  Move the second call there and chain it to the first.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to move yor second call (calls) to `componentDidMount` in a way like:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var th = this;
  var coins; 
  axios.get(this.state.coinListJson)
    .then(function(result) {
       coins = result.data.coins;
       return Promise.all(coins.map(function(val){
         var url = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/"+val.id+"/?convert=EUR";
         return axios.get(url);
       });
     })
     .then(function(result) {
        // process the result, change state accordingly
        th.setState({
            coinList: coins
            // subResult: result
        }) 
      });
}
```